# cannot retain id of first table in left join

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I am using sails waterline ORM and i have three tables in my model layer

1-**s_class**

```
attributes: {
c_title:{
type:'string',
required: true
},
sec:{
   collection:'s_section',
   via:"cls"
  },
  s_session:{
   model:'s_session',
   columnName:'session'
  }

}
```

2-**s_section**

```
 attributes: {
  sec_title:{
type:'string'
},
  sec_priority:{
type:'integer',
required: true
},
  cls:{
   collection:'s_class',
   via:"sec"
  }
}
```

3-**s_form**

```
attributes: {
 studentName:{
  type:'string'
 },
s_class:{
    columnName:'s_class',
    model:'s_class'
  },
   s_section:{
    columnName:'s_section',
    model:'s_section'
  }
}
```

i assigned both class and section to student which are saved in **s_form** table.when i write a query to get a student's record alongwith his class and section.something like this:

```
 s_form.query("SELECT * FROM s_form LEFT OUTER JOIN s_class ON s_form.s_class=s_class.id LEFT OUTER JOIN s_section ON s_form.s_section=s_section.id",function(err,forms){
        if(!err)
        else{
            res.json(forms);
}
    });
```

it populates record of section and class but also affects auto increment primery key of s_form.actually this is because s_section and s_class also have default auto increment primery keys which after populating conflicts and in this case i got id of s_section.

i want to get id of s_form.is there any way to avoid this conflict and overriding of id without affecting default behavior of primery keys????

**Note**

s_form table  contains custom columns means the columns mentioned above are static but it also contain columns which are created at runtime.that's why i can't use built in **populate()** query method nor i can specify column names like instead of select *.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your edited / updated post you I would query query to retrieve your column names prior to executing the query so that you can iterate over them and pass the table name as a prefix to each column name. This would allow you to avoid any conflicts.

You can use the following to get column names

```
SELECT * 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='yourdatabasename' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='yourtablename';
```

You can use this after your dynamic tables are created and save it in a variable so you don't have to keep doing it on every query.

Comment: after this query needed to be written in loop over coloumn names...like if i find all the column names in an array columns i can't do anything like this "select columns from table "..

Comment: And if i use loop then how can i specify the where the join should be used in loop.isn't there any simple solution to this???

Comment: you would use that query just to get the column names, then loop over column names to create your select statement. You would prefix each column name with the table name so their would be no collisions. then you insert these new names in place of the ```*``` in your original column. If you save this as a variable you will not have to re-do this initial query every time.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first you can have sails do this for you

```
s_form.find().populate('').populate('').exec(function(err,forms){/*....*/});
```

If you want to use query then you need to explicitly name your fields in order to avoid the conflict that will happen.

Instead of `SELECT * FROM`

You should specific each field so can rename the Id field to avoid these conflicts.

```
SELECT 
   s_class.c_title, s_class.id as classId,
   s_section.sec_title,s_section.sec_priority,s_section.id as sectionId,
   s_form.studentName,s_form.id as formId
FROM FROM s_form LEFT OUTER JOIN s_class ON s_form.s_class=s_class.id LEFT OUTER JOIN s_section ON s_form.s_section=s_section.id
```

Comment: oh m really sorry i've forgotten to mention that s_form contains custom fields.........see edit please :(